Sticky headers in css and html but relative to the grandparent container
I am using the ShimmeredDetailsList from fluent UI 8 and I want to make some rows sticky.
The problem is that this component renders the items inside virtualized pages and if I set position: sticky on them, they will leave the container as soon as the page disappears. I want to make them sticky relative to the grandparent container that contains all the pages.
I used display: 'contents' and the sticky position works, but the table breaks.
So this is my general question, is there any good way to make an element sticky relative to the grandparent container?
<div class="container">
  <div class="virtual-page">
    <div class="header">Header 1</div> <!-- should stick but relatively to the container -->
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="virtual-page">
    <div class="item" >Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="header">Header 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="virtual-page">
    <div class="Header">Header 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  </div>
</div>

.container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.virtual-page {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid teal;
  width: 100%;
  // display: contents; adding this the stickiness will work 
but we cant do that in our case
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: aqua;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.item {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

Here is an example of the issue: https://codepen.io/bill-georgoulas/pen/PorbQNW

Can you add some code of what you've tried so far?

updated the question!

Please [edit] your question to include your CSS.

Related, possible duplicate: How to make sticky to grandparent element?

yeah, there wasn't good solution there
